# Haskell IO Bool fold question

Tags: haskell, io, fold

How can I write a function that does logical and function between the elements of the list?

I have written this:

```
iand :: [IO Bool] -> IO Bool

iand [] = return (True)
iand (x:xs) = do
  a <- x 
  b <- iand(xs)
  return (a && b)
```

But that seems to be unconscice.

How can this function be rewritten with foldM (liftM)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Prelude function [`and :: [Bool] -> Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aand) almost does what you want, but it's not monadic.  Generally speaking, to lift a one-argument function into a monad, you'll want Control.Monad's [`liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> b a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aliftM); however, to be more general, you can use the Prelude's [`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afmap).  All monads are functors<sup>1</sup>, so this is ok.  Thus, you can use

```
fand' :: Functor f => f [Bool] -> f Bool
fand' = fmap and
```

However, at least 90% of the time, I would just write that inline as `fmap and xs`, or more probably `and <$> xs`, using Control.Applicative's [`<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a%3C%24%3E) synonym for `fmap`.

Of course, as I'm sure you noticed, this isn't what you want.  For that, you need the Prelude's [`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asequence).  You now have a function `[m a] -> m [a]`, and a function `f [Bool] -> f Bool`, so we can combine these:

```
mand :: Monad m => [m Bool] -> m Bool
mand = liftM and . sequence
```

I switched to `liftM` from `fmap` because, although `fmap`'s "nicer" in some sense, it would impose an additional `Functor m` constraint.  That *shouldn't* be a problem, but it could be for historical reasons, so I played it safe.

Also, you might ask "How would I have ever known about `sequence`"?  The answer to that is the wonderful [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), which allows you to search for Haskell functions by name *or type*.  So, since you knew about `liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`, you might have realized you needed something like `Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`; Hoogling for that [does indeed turn up `sequence`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%5bm+a%5d+-%3E+m+%5ba%5d).

---

**1:** Or, at least, they should be—for historical reasons, though, this isn't always the case.

Comment: Thanks! But is says: "Couldn't match expected type `m' against inferred type `[]' " to mand function. What's the problem there?

Comment: @Dmitry: Oops, that's because I typoed.  I asserted that `mand :: Monad m => m [Bool] -> m Bool`, which is obviously stupid, since the *point* of this exercise was to build you a function with type `Monad m => [m Bool] -> m Bool`.  If you fix that type assertion, everything works.  I've edited my answer correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `liftM` to turn `and` (which has type `[Bool] -> Bool`) into a function of type `IO [Bool] -> IO Bool` and `sequence` to turn your `[IO Bool]` into an `IO [Bool]`.

So your function becomes:

```
iand ibs = liftM and (sequence ibs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be `iand list = foldl (&&) True list` ?

Comment: No. That would be a function of type `[Bool] -> Bool`, which acts like normal `and`, but is less lazy. What Dmitry wants is a function of type `[IO Bool] -> IO Bool`.

Comment: Right. Missed that. Sorry for the confusion.